# Permission Issues regarding Plugin updates & FTP transfers

Tags: plugins, permissions

I am looking for a little assistance tracking down my permission issues regarding updating plugins from my admin page or transfering files via FTP into the wp-content file.

I have been searching for an answer for a while but nothing seems to be working.

I have tried: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ~/html/blog/wp-content` but it does not work.

My permissions for the wp-content folder are: `drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Jan  1 13:16 wp-content`

`ps aux | grep apache` (1st line): `root      8879  0.0  2.2 125064 22916 ?        Ss   Jan01   0:09 /usr/sbin/apache2`

`ps aux | grep wp-content`: `pi       25195  0.0  0.0   4380   564 pts/0    S+   22:39   0:00 grep --color=auto`

I am thinking that because apache is 'root' and wp-content is 'pi' that might be the problem, but I do not know how to fix it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress needs a proper `read - write` permission to work. To make sure everythings fine, try this:

Go to you `public_html` folder and run the commands

```
chown www-data:www-data  -R *
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

After that, you might wanna tighten your security, [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress)

That's what works on me, hope it works on you too...